# Selecting rows that fail to match this join's criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm error checking a search index table (asIndex) that is built by a script from 25 tables.

Both the asIndex and Evaluations tables have multiple rows per address.

So this query was an attempt to be sure that everywhere an index row has Evaluation = 'blue' that there was at least one row in Evaluations where Evaluation is set to 'blue'.
It works but it produces 40K rows.

```
SELECT 
    ev.`Street Name`, 
    ev.`Street Number`, 
    ev.Evaluation
FROM 
  `tblEvaluations` ev,
  `asIndex` asi
WHERE asi.`Evaluation` = 'blue'
AND asi.`StreetName` = ev.`Street Name`
AND asi.`StreetNumber` = ev.`Street Number`;
```

What I need to do is make a query that will list any address which has a blue Evaluation in the asIndex but for which there is no matching address in Evaluations table with a blue Evaluation value.

How do I select that negative match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a left join.

```
SELECT 
    asi.`Street Name`, 
    asi.`Street Number`, 
    asi.Evaluation
FROM 
  `asIndex` asi ledt join
  `tblEvaluations` ev on asi.`StreetName` = ev.`Street Name`
      AND asi.`StreetNumber` = ev.`Street Number`
WHERE asi.`Evaluation` = 'blue'
   AND ev.`Street Name` is Null;
```

Comment: Strictly, it'd be "one option" not "need". You also have NOT IN and in other RDBMS you can have EXCEPT too... :-)

Comment: engineers. . . always focused on the details.

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS is cleanest and standard SQL too

```
SELECT 
    ev.`Street Name`, 
    ev.`Street Number`, 
    ev.Evaluation
FROM 
  `tblEvaluations` ev
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM   `asIndex` asi
           WHERE
    asi.`Evaluation` = 'blue'
    AND asi.`StreetName` = ev.`Street Name`
    AND asi.`StreetNumber` = ev.`Street Number
    );
```

Edit: evan had a point (deleted their answer which may be what you want). It depends how you filter for blue.

Comment: OK, but shouldn't the SELECT ev.`Street Name`...  be selecting asi.`StreetName` etc ?  It seems like in that syntax ev.`Street Name`, 
ev.`Street Number`, ev.Evaluation are necessarily null?